# Julia code sent to repl is a different environment than code typed into repl

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

If I have a julia doc open and am working through a script, I can highlight a selection and pres Ctrl+Enter, or even open a popupmenu and choose `Julia: Execute Code in REPL` using the Julia Language Support extension.

If I define a variable

```
x = 1
```

and send that to the repl, all hunky dory. I can send it again and again and it will print 1.

If however, I go down to the actual terminal window and type `x` into the repl I received the error that x is not defined. This is happening to code inside a function inside a module, though I'm not sure that's relevant. The reverse is true as well, code typed into the repl is not defined in the same space as code sent to execute in the repl.

Below is Ctrl+enter sent to repl and simply typing t.

[image]

Comment: This is intended behavior on VSCode, are you trying to turn it off? The simple solution would be to just decide to use one or the other.

Comment: I think I would like to turn it off. I am more accustomed to RStudio's repl environment where I can enter some quick one liners into the console to experiment with the existing environment. I was unsuccessful looking for a related setting in the preferences.

Comment: The issue is that typed text is executed in the `Main` module rather than the file's module. I also find it extremely annoying: https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/3024. To work around, you can either copy and paste into REPL instead of Ctrl+Enter or edit the file and Ctrl+Enter the new text.